# how to change text position in a textview?

Tags: android, text, textview

I have two textview with text inside. The text start from the beginning of the textview:

[image]

I want to move to right the text inside(title and author) of 10dp, what can I do ?

Comment: [`android:layout_marginLeft=10dp`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_marginLeft)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your `TextView` if you just want to move the text not the `TextView`

```
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
```

or

```
android:paddingStart="10dp" // prefer this
```

But add this if you just want to move the `TextView` itself

```
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
```

or

```
android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
```

**Note:** You can use combination of both also.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this.

you can use padding or margin,

see the image to get a description...

you can set then in your textview the padding

```
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
```

or

`android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"`

[image]